# Font size render larger

Tags: android, css, angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

All fonts in my app that are smaller than 8px are rendering with 8px size.

The bug only happens in the phone, if I test in a browser with `ionic serve` everything works fine.

When I build and debug in the phone, all fonts size are limited to a minimum of 8px. If I change to a bigger size works fine.

[image: Debug shot this]

Tried `text-size-adjust:none` and has no effect on the problem.

Using Galaxy J5 with android 6.0.1 and Moto G3 with android 6.0

Comment: What phone and OS?

Comment: @Paulie_D Galaxy J5 with android 6.0.1 and Moto G3 with android 6.0